# Multiple parameters to methods in F#

Tags: f#

I've got a class written in F# that I'm consuming in C#, that defines a method `Render`:

```
member this.Render template (context: IContext) =
    let tokens = Lexer.tokenize template
    let parser = new DefaultParser([for filter in _filters -> filter])

    let resp = new StringBuilder()
    for node in parser.Parse tokens None do
        ignore <| resp.Append(node.render context)

    resp.ToString()
```

The signature of this method is `template:string -> (IContext -> string)`, which of course reads as "member `Render` takes a `string` parameter, then returns a function that takes an `IContext` and produces a string.

If I change the declaration from "member" to a let binding, defining it as a function local to the class definition:

```
let Render template (context: IContext) = ...
```

Then the signature becomes what you would expect it to be - `string -> IContext -> string`, which reads "`Render` takes a string, then an `IContext` and produces a string".

Is there a way to make a member behave like the let binding? This is causing issues consuming this member from C#, as the signature becomes `Render(string, FastFunc<IContext, string>)`, which is not overly usable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to expose to C#, you should write it tupled style:

```
> type Foo =
-   member this.Bar (param1, param2) =  param1 + param2;;

type Foo =
  class
    member Bar : param1:int * param2:int -> int
  end
```

That'll expose a normal .NET style method.

Comment: Make sure you provide names for the objects in the tuple.

Comment: sorry - that was for a slightly different question. your suggestion works for concrete members, but it doesn't work for interfaces defined in f# and then implemented in c#. those come across as Tuple<type, type>